# CoreData - xcode7 reference not found

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a project that is using coredata which was originally written in Xcode6. When I make amendments to the entities and re-generate the files I get 2 new files which have +coredataproperties at the end. I have just added a new entity to a table but when I try and reference it I get an error in code saying that the object dosent exist even though when I debug the managed object at run time I can see the object in the returned list.

```
            for(Products *product in Data){
                //set deleted to true
                product.awaitingDelete = [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE];
                product.awaitingUpload = [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE];
            }
```

Product.awaitingDelete comes us with an error saying that its not found on the products object.

In the .h file it looks like this..

```
#import "Products+CoreDataProperties.h"

@implementation Products (CoreDataProperties)

@dynamic awaitingDelete; 
@dynamic awaitingUpload; 
@dynamic jobID; 
@dynamic orderNumber; 
@dynamic productGUID; 
@dynamic productID; 
@dynamic productNotes; 
@dynamic roomName; 
@dynamic toBeDeleted; 
@dynamic windowGUID; 
@dynamic windowID; 
@dynamic windowName; 
@dynamic windowNumber; 
@dynamic windowType; 
@dynamic containsAnswers; 
@dynamic inWindow;

@end
```

and when I run up the code and debug the products object I can see the entities

> Printing description of product:  (entity:
>   Products; id: 0xd000000000b00058
>    ;
>   data: {
>       awaitingDelete = nil;
>       awaitingUpload = nil;
>       containsAnswers =     (
>           "0xd0000000056c0046 ",
>           "0xd000000005600046 ",
>           "0xd000000005700046 ",
>           "0xd000000005680046 ",
>           "0xd000000005580046 ",
>           "0xd0000000054c0046 ",
>           "0xd000000005540046 ",
>           "0xd0000000055c0046 ",
>           "0xd000000005500046 ",
>           "0xd000000005640046 "
>       );
>       inWindow = "0xd00000000048005c ";
>       jobID = 122;
>       orderNumber = 0;
>       productGUID = "B281A604-26D0-4CD6-A2A6-AAF6EB0B2846";
>       productID = 262;
>       productNotes = nil;
>       roomName = Master;
>       toBeDeleted = nil;
>       windowGUID = "8738FC28-9206-4935-9DC4-7E52030A77DC";
>       windowID = 186;
>       windowName = 01;
>       windowNumber = 2;
>       windowType = Standard; })

I am guessing I have missed something with xcode7, can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe you can check the relationships between the entities.I ever got runtime error caused by this.

Comment: You mean you need to import the new file?

Comment: It seems that there was an old version of the files being referenced in Xcode. I have now managed to get this working.